# Installed version 1.9.1 - "Sitemap" menu option missing

Tags: magento-1.9, sitemaps

I've just updated Magento to version 1.9.1 and I cannot find the sitemap menu. I was on version 1.9.0.1 previously and it was located at:

Top menu - Catalog - Google Sitemap

but that option just simply isn't there any more. Is this an error with my installation/upgrade or has it been removed or moved?

Could someone who is also using 1.9.1 check if they have the menu option please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check your var/logs. I upgraded from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1 and I can see Google Sitemap menu.

Comment: Ok so I deleted the system.log and then logged in to the admin panel, the below is the subsequent system.log can anyone point in the right direction as to how to fix this? I am a bit of a magento and coding novice!

Comment: 2014-11-28T10:19:00+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 6: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 5 and body  in /home/fatpound/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173

Comment: 2014-11-28T10:19:00+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: &lt;/body&gt;  in /home/fatpound/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173

Comment: 2014-11-28T10:19:00+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]:        ^  in /home/fatpound/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173

Comment: There are other lines also but all relate to what seems to be the same issue with feed.php

Comment: have you cleared magento cache after upgrade? remove `cache` folder under `var` i.e. var/cache

Comment: Yep, cache and session cleared. Since my last post I've fixed the above errors in the system.log but still no Sitemaps menu. I've reinstalled magento and still the same. Tried installing a fresh version on a fresh database (none of my files or database) and the menu is there, as soon as I install it over my database - Sitemap menu disappears!! I've tried the database repair tool but it says nothing to repair. I even tried just typing /sitemap after my admin url and it just redirects back to the dashboard. I'm completely at a loss of what to try next. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bizarrely Sitemap was disabled in System - Configuration - Advanced - Advanced. God knows how but there it is, simple as that. All good now. Thanks for the help guys, the system.log tip was a good one as I had errors I wasn't aware of that are now fixed :)